# How to check the text that is already in RecyclerView or not

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

```
public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TITLE = "Chats";

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference myRef;
List<Listdata> list;
RecyclerView recyclerview;

public static ChatsFragment newInstance() {

    return new ChatsFragment();
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle b) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, group, false);
    recyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.rview);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("message");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                UserDetails userdetails = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserDetails.class);
                Listdata listdata = new Listdata();
                String name = userdetails.getName();
                String message = userdetails.getMessage();
                listdata.setName(name);
                listdata.setMessage(message);
                list.add(listdata);

            }

            RecyclerviewAdapter recycler = new RecyclerviewAdapter(list);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
            recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

I have a recycler `CardView` with a list of names.The names sent by the firebase database. When I sent the same name twice it shows count 2.I want to check a name that is already listed or not. If the name is already in `RecyclerView` I want to show the count 2. How to check the name list and show the count.

Comment: Post sufficient code first to look into issue

Comment: Please post code .

Comment: please see the edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            UserDetails userdetails = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserDetails.class);
            String name = userdetails.getName();
            String message = userdetails.getMessage();

            if (list.contains(new ListData(name,message))) {
               list.set(list.indexOf(new ListData(name, message)), new ListData(name + "check", message);
            } else {
               list.add(new ListData(name, message));
            }
    }
```

In Place of "2" you can code for incrementing of count. I considered message as a count

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it does not work. When i send same name and message at second time it also  add in the list.

Comment: now run this code, and see is previously assigned "name" changed to "namecheck" or it became a new entry

Comment: if (list.contains(new ListData(name,message)))         This statement returns false everytime even the name is already in arraylist.

Comment: Hey @velayutham can you please share your code to me. On Gmail??

Comment: Please share your mail id @ankit

Comment: ankitpatidar030@gmail.com

Comment: Please check ur mail. I will send my full code. Check it and give a solution.Thanks

Comment: Hy please send me snap of firebase database

Answer (score 0):

public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference myRef;
List<ListData> list;
RecyclerView recyclerview;
HashMap<String,String> hashMap;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle b) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, group, false);
    recyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.rview);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("message");
    hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
                       for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                UserDetails userdetails = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserDetails.class);
                String name = userdetails.getName();
                String message = userdetails.getMessage();

                if (hashMap.containsKey(name)) {
                    if (!hashMap.get(name).equalsIgnoreCase(message)) {

                        hashMap.remove(name);
                        hashMap.put(name + "-2", message);
                    }
                } else
                    hashMap.put(name, message);

            }

            list = convertHashToObjectList(hashMap);
            RecyclerViewAdapter recycler = new RecyclerViewAdapter(list);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
private ArrayList<ListData> convertHashToObjectList(HashMap<String, String> chatHashmap){

    ArrayList<ListData> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: chatHashmap.entrySet()) {
        listData.add(new ListData(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));
    }

    return listData;

}
```

}

This the Answer given by @ankit. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Please accept my code. Because it was given my me. So points should be reputed to me.